# Can we define a modern team site as the root site for our tenant instead of the default communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, site-collection, administration

We have a new tenant created on June 2019, and it comes with a root communication site. Now we want to have this root as a modern team site, mainly because we want to embed and show other Office 365 groups' calendars using the "Group Calendar" web part, which is not available inside the modern communication site:

[image]

So can anyone advice how can we define a modern team site as the root site for our tenant instead of the communication site? and is this recommended ? If this is not recommended, then can we show Group Calendars inside communication modern site?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I am able to add the multiple "Group Calendar" web parts on root communication site.

**Proof**:

[image]

---

Also, as per the Microsoft official documentation, [Replace your root site - Limitations](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/modern-root-site#limitations):

> - The site you select as the new root site must be a *communication site (SITEPAGEPUBLISHING#0) or a modern team site that isn't connected to a Microsoft 365 group (STS#3)* and where **the publishing feature has never been activated**.
> - The current root site **can't** be connected to a Microsoft 365 group.
> - When you replace the root site, both the current site and the new site can't be hub sites or associated with a hub.

So, you can use modern team site which is not connected to Microsoft 365 group as the root site for your tenant.

Comment: but how did you add Group Calendar inside communication sites, they are not appearing in my case

Comment: I haven't done anything from my side. Group calendar web part is available automatically in communication site.